# How can I perform this? (Example inside)

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

http://dev4.catechismclass.com/
So on this site when I scroll down to an item and click 'quick view' A window pops up with more details about the item and if I click on the grey sides the window closes. I would like the functionality for my website. Can you guys point me in the right direction as to how I should go about writing the code for this?

Comment: Google "html modal popup tutorial"

Comment: have you worked with bootstrap? that can be done easily with bootstrap modals

Comment: @anguswild I have worked with Bootstrap 3 but I guess I never saw it. Thanks for the information guys! I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download bootstrap from [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/) and add the following code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#JorgeModal">Open Modal</button>

<div id="JorgeModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>All your content</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information!